# Python pandas data frame transformation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to transform a panda data frame , its original structure is

```
USER_ID , Buisiness_ID, Rating
abcde   , a1b1c2      , 3
abcde   , a2b3c2      , 3
afgh    , a1b3        ,1
```

and I'm trying to transform it into

```
        a1b1c2       a2b3c2      a1b3
abcde     3            3
afgh                               1
```

what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) operation, which looks like reshaping the table from long to wide:

```
import pandas as pd
print df.pivot(index='USER_ID', columns='Buisiness_ID')
```

Output:

```
             Rating            
Buisiness_ID a1b1c2 a1b3 a2b3c2
USER_ID                        
abcde             3  NaN      3
afgh            NaN    1    NaN
```

Comment: but  the user_id contain duplicate entries, and it's not allowing me to reshape.